# How to gather string form easygui.enterbox

Tags: python, string, easygui

Like

```
Enter = easygui.enterbox
print(Enter.text)
```

I don't know how to do that.What string name form easygui.enterbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enterbox` is a function, quote from the [tutorial](http://www.ferg.org/easygui/easygui.html#-enterbox):

> enterbox(msg='Enter something.', title=' ', default='', strip=True)
>
> Show a box in which a user can enter some text.   You may optionally
>   specify some default text, which will appear in the enterbox when it
>   is displayed.
>
> Returns the text that the user entered, or None if he
>   cancels the operation.

Example:

```
import easygui

value = easygui.enterbox()
print(value)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am sorry about abadoning this question.  Thank you.  I used Python2 syntax .